# Joining tables, SQL syntax error in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, join, spring-data-jpa, left-join

I'm trying to join two seperate tables in Spring Boot but getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.javaguide.springboot.model.UserUserMetaDto(um.lastname, u.username) FROM userme' at line 1
```

The tables I wish to join is User and UserMeta.

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String username;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonManagedReference
    UserMeta userMeta; 
    
// Setters & Getters...
```

**UserMeta:**

```
@Table(name = "usermeta")
@Entity
public class UserMeta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String lastname;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private User user;

    //Setters and Getters...
```

**The UserMeta repository, UserMetaRepository:**

```
public interface UserMetaRepository extends CrudRepository<UserMeta, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT new net.javaguide.springboot.model.UserUserMetaDto(um.lastname, u.username) "
            + "FROM usermeta um LEFT JOIN user u ON um.user_id = u.id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserUserMetaDto> fetchUserUserMetaJoin();
}
```

**The data transfer object for joining the tables, "UserUserMetaDto":**

```
public class UserUserMetaDto {

    private String username;
    private String lastname;

    public UserUserMetaDto(String lastname, String username) {
        this.username = username;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    // GEtters & Setters..

    public String toString() {
        return "username=" + username + " ,lastname=" + lastname;
    }
}
```

I suspect that there is something wrong with the syntax, however. I have been running the following query in MySQL Workbench which works perfectly.

```
SELECT u.username, um.lastname FROM user u LEFT JOIN usermeta um ON um.user_id = u.id;
```

Comment: ...you told Spring that you want to use a native query, so why not just use the above?  BTW...the query you are currently using is valid neither in MySQL or JPQL.

Comment: I can't use this one: `SELECT u.username, um.lastname FROM user u LEFT JOIN usermeta um ON um.user_id = u.id;` since I need a DTO to retrieve the data. 
Do you have a solution for retrieving the username and lastname @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: If I'm not using the nativeQuery I'm getting the error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: usermeta is not mapped`

Comment: Well you could change the method signature to `List<Object>`.  Not sure about what to do with DTO, but it should be possible.

Comment: Yepp.. that worked. Pretty straight forward. Thx

Comment: There probably is a way to do this with native SQL plus a DTO, or using JPQL.

Comment: Yeah, problem with just retrieving a Object is that it is not a json-object. Which is better for the client side. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: It is your choice.  If you want to avoid creating a new POJO, then use `List<Object>`.